# Removing ":" from namespace in a XML file parsing

Tags: python, xml, xml-namespaces, python-2.6, xml.etree

I am trying to modify XML file using ***xml.etree.ElementTree*** on Python **2.6.6** (due to restrictions) and facing **ns0** issue. I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830673/parsing-xml-with-namespaces-using-elementtree-in-python) issue and used **ET._namespace_map[uri] = prefix** as suggested which removed ns0 but the element tags still has the **:** value. How do we remove it or does it impact the validity of the XML file when we use if for further processing?

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Seed xmlns="http://www.example.com">
    <TagA>
        <TagB>B</TagB>
        <TagC>c</TagC>
    </TagA>
</Seed>
```

**Script**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('sample.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

try:
    ET.register_namespace("","http://example.com")
except AttributeError:
    def register_namespace(prefix, uri):
        ET._namespace_map[uri] = prefix
    register_namespace("","http://www.example.com")
tree.write('sample.xml')
```

**Note:** I could not use *lxml* or other xml.etree that is supported only from 2.7 version.

Comment: @mzjn The original file does not carry that notation. After we parse it with the xml.etree only, ":" is getting added. I am fine as long as, it does not invalidate the file.

Comment: What is "the original file"? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/8113296/407651

Comment: @mzjn Thanks for sharing the thread, looks like same issue. I will go through it. I have added sample XML data and script as requested.